# Isolating electric signals on the body

Tags: wireless, electromagnetism

It is a well known fact that EM signals propagate on the human body. For example, if I had one hand on a microwave, my body would act as an antenna and a receiver would be able to detect the waves being radiated from my body.

My question is, suppose I had my left and right hand touch two electrical objects emitting different EM signals (say a microwave and a hair dryer).

a) would a receiver be able to disambiguate/separate the two signals.

b) is there a way to isolate the two signals as it travels through my body?

Comment: This question is quite vague and unclear. How are the EM signals Different? Frequency, amplitude, power, spectral content? What do you mean with "Isolate (...) as it travels through my body"? I think this question stems from a deep lack of understanding of EM principles, and can't really be answered because it's by it's underlying assumptions wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an EM wave would (if it had an opinion) prefer a human body not to be present because it would pass further at a higher amplitude. In other words, a human body is, more than likely, liable to attenuate an EM wave. This means your opening claim is largely rubbish and questions can't be answered that appear to be based on rubbish.

Comment: @user2565609 Depends on the frequency of the 'EM signal'

Comment: The Motorola pagers, at 400MHz, used a 2" by 1" "short" antenna to couple into the human.

Answer (score 1):

You forget an important property of EM waves, their wavelength (or frequency). Also, EM waves can travel through space so even when both microwave and hairdryer emit EM waves when in weightlessness, all signals would be present everywhere. i.e. the presence of you or something conductive is not required.

a) assuming the receiver is capable of that, yes. On a [spectrum analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_analyzer) I would be able to see the microwave emitting at around 2.5 GHz and the hairdryer emitting at whatever frequency, it will depend on the model.

b) No, all signals will be present everywhere. Their power intensity might vary though. Some signals (depending on their wavelength) have more trouble going through your body, reflect or travel only through your skin. Other signals act as if you're not even there. Artificial structures can be made to make certain signals follow a certain path. An example is the window with the metal mesh in the microwave. The mesh stops the microwave signal from escaping (their wavelength is too long to go through the holes) but ordinary light (light is also an EM wave !) can pass through since it has a much smaller wavelength.

Comment: a) Yes, but you won't be able to disentangle the two time-domain signals. I am interested in whether it would be possible to do that. b) Let us assume the receiver only picks up signals that are transmitting through the body, and it is not a wireless receiver that picks up everything in the air. Would signal separation be possible?

Comment: Regarding separation, EM signals follow the Superposition principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle so the two signals always combine into one. You still do not get that there is no difference between a  signal travelling through the air or through a body. I think you need to study EM waves and principles a lot more.

Comment: @user2562609 checkout MIMO, separation of signals of the same frequency by path length differences.

Answer (score 0):

From the view of electromagnetic waves, your body is nothing more than a conducting surface. It doesn't make a fundamental difference whether you touch another conducting surface or not.

If you directly touch an antenna —don't know how you are trying to manage that by touching the **grounded** body of a microwave oven— your body becomes part of that antenna, meaning there is no EM wave required to have the electrons inside you move. You are directly connected to the sender circuit.

When you touch two or more sender circuits directly, your body acts as a complex resistance between the antennas. Again, no EM wave involved. A bit of electrical energy is stored in you, most of it is turned into heat.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHKufF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

These are two voltages sources, each one is grounded. When you touch both antennas (and aside the fact you are also grounded by a roughly 1kΩ resistance), current is flowing between the two sources through ground and YOU.

$$I=\frac{U_1-U_2}{R}$$

If these two sources have the same frequency, it's not possible to tell apart which source accounts for which part of the current. They are just a sum. If they have different frequencies, it is possible to tell that apart by looking at the longer of both time periods and see how the shorter one changes the current during the longer one.